# Why is the white ranger's transformation different in Power Rangers Dino Thunder?

Tags: plot-explanation, power-rangers, power-rangers-dino-thunder

In [Power Rangers Dino Thunder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Rangers_Dino_Thunder) the Red, Yellow, and Blue ranger don't transform when they first touch a Dinogem. Tommy Oliver modifiest their gems to morph them into rangers. However, Trent Mercer, the White ranger, was instantly transformed by touching the white gem.

Why was the white ranger's transformation different from the others? Or i missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Power Rangers Dino Thunder wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Rangers_Dino_Thunder#Dino_Rangers) page has this to say:

> Tommy (known often as Dr. O) himself joins the team as the Black Dino
>   Ranger, and they are also later joined by Trent Mercer as the White
>   Dino Ranger, with the powers of invisibility and camouflage,
>   respectively. Trent must deal with the inner struggle of good and
>   evil, as Tommy himself once had to do as the evil Green Ranger, due to
>   the fact that he gained his powers from a raw Dino Gem in Mesogog's
>   lab, with the powers originally intended to be Mesogog's.

I haven't actually seen the series,  but this passage leads me to believe that the Dino Gem that Trent found wasn't exactly the same as the other two, and that's why his transformation is different.

Comment: Dino thunder is the only series which i like the most, Your wiki lines are rite, i know that Mesogog is working on the white gem to take its power but he has nothing to do with morphing because Mesogog  doesnot want to become ranger so why whould he make morpher out of it. He is trying to take the power out of the white gem i think. Othervise +1 for your efforts